# Parallel.Invoke: limping execution time

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Thanks to the help from people on this site I am moving my first steps into parallel programming.

Here is the C# (simplified) code that I am currently testing.

```
do
{
    // PRN data download to the waveform generator...
    // Response data acquisition from the oscilloscope...
    // etc...

    t0 = Win32.MM_GetTime();

    // Serial evaluation of the data DFT;
    // execution time constantly = 0.785 s.
    //DSP.DFT_2_F(D1, ref R1, ref X1);
    //DSP.DFT_2_F(D2, ref R2, ref X2);

    // Parallel evaluation of the data DFT;
    // execution time = 0.395 s, but...
    Parallel.Invoke(
    () => DSP.DFT_2_F(D1, ref R1, ref X1),
    () => DSP.DFT_2_F(D2, ref R2, ref X2)
    );

    lblTMis.Text = ((double)(Win32.MM_GetTime() - t0) / 1000.0).ToString();

    // Plot the measurement results...
    // etc...
}
while (bMisuraOn);
```

Now, while the Serial DFT evaluation constantly takes 0.785 s, the parallel version only takes 0.395 s but time to time, say every 3-4 measurement loops, the execution time jumps to 0.838 s.
What I also noticed is that, after 50-60 loops, the execution time stabilizes to 0.395 s with only very occasional jumps; if I restart the measurement loop, without exiting the program, the "limping" shows up again and again disappears after a while.

It looks like, to me, that sometimes the Parallel.Invoke decides to behave as Serial...

Is this correct or have I done something wrong?
There is any way to get always the same (fast) execution time?

Ciao and thanks for the attention.

Franco

Comment: Normally, it doesn't behave serially. Maybe your function has varying performance? Duplicate the invoke statement 10 times and run a profiler. You have good chances of "catching" one case where it took longer. The profiler shows why.; Or, remove the Parallel.Invoke. Is performance still varying?

Comment: ... Maybe your function has varying performance?
... Or, remove the Parallel.Invoke. Is performance still varying?

No, during the test I always use the same Data for the function and, on the other hand, the Serial version (commented out in the posted code), with the same Data and with Parallel block removed, constantly takes 0.785 s +/- 1 ms.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `Parallel.Invoke`:

> Executes each of the provided actions, possibly in parallel.

Threading isn't guaranteed to execute asynchronously, it just usually does.  I'm not sure how to get around it further, but this at least explains the behavior.

Comment: < Threading isn't guaranteed to execute asynchronously, it just usually does...>
I have found on the Web several situations where the Parallel.Invoke behaves as Serial but I haven't found anything explaining why, in the same block of code, sometimes works Serial and sometimes Parallel.
Thanks.